# Python - Turn a list into words separated by lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6

How can I print a list, say `[‘White’,’Yellow’,’Blue’,’Red’,’Orange’]` like a “list of words?” That means that I want my list to be printed like so:

```
White
Yellow
Blue
Red
Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a loop?

```
>>> colors = ['White', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Orange']
>>> for color in colors:
...     print(color)
...
White
Yellow
Blue
Red
Orange
```

Or create a string separated by line feeds and print it directly

```
>>> print('\n'.join(colors))
White
Yellow
Blue
Red
Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `join`:

```py
colors = ['White', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Orange']

print('\n'.join(colors))
```

Answer (score 1):

At least three obvious ways I can think of off-hand:

Straightforward print loop:

```
for x in iterable:
    print(x)
```

`print` with varargs unpacking and a newline separator:

```
print(*iterable, sep="\n")
```

Explict join with newline:

```
print("\n".join(iterable))
```

From here on out it gets more esoteric, but one particular case worth mentioning (because it's basically a faster version of the explicit loop that avoids trying to pull a complete iterator into memory at once, and avoids per-item bytecode execution on the CPython reference interpreter by pushing all the work to C):

```
import sys

sys.stdout.writelines(map('{}\n'.format, iterable))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate on your list and print each word.

Just like this:

```
list = ["White","Yellow","Blue","Red","Orange"]

for word in list:
    print(word)
```